# NoSuchMethodError TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener

Tags: java, android

Recently I encountered `NoSuchMethodError` for `TabLayout.onTabSelectedListener` in Android `sdk` version 26, but this method is introduced in `sdk` version 22, what is the problem? I've checked and made sure all necessary `sdk` tools is installed.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tabLayout2[0] = (LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
                tabTextView[0] = (TextView) tabLayout2[0].getChildAt(1);
                tabTextView[0].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tabLayout2[0] = (LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
                tabTextView[0] = (TextView) tabLayout2[0].getChildAt(1);
                tabTextView[0].setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

These are my dependencies

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13.26.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

My full error log

```
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime: Process: sdk.at.dbs.example.com.testsdk, PID: 21900
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method addOnTabSelectedListener(Landroid/support/design/widget/TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener;)V in class Landroid/support/design/widget/TabLayout; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout' appears in /data/app/sdk.at.dbs.example.com.testsdk-2/base.apk:classes2.dex)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.tetralogiq.at.member.ui.home.HomeCardStackActivity.c(HomeCardStackActivity.java:354)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.tetralogiq.at.member.ui.home.HomeCardStackActivity.onCreate(HomeCardStackActivity.java:145)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
03-30 09:23:30.411 21900 21900 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where you are using it?

Comment: @MirunaRadu i've added that to the question. thank you for any advice in advance

Comment: Can you post your full error log aswell?

Comment: @majuran hi i have added that into the question, thank you

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener) it is deprecated.

Comment: @Abra It is not 100% deprecated, Android deprecated most old support libraries to ensure people to move AndroidX. [see this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener) , It was moved to AndroidX/Material

Comment: @JIASHENGHEW I suggest you to update your support libraries version, Or move to AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

You should consider updating your libraries:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0
```